# Dúvida com posicionamento de imagens

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma imagem para o logo, quero que ela fique sempre posicionada no centro da tela para todos os dispositivos.

Estou usando o [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).

**CSS**

```
.relative{
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="relative">
    <img src="~/Content/images/Checkmark.fw.png" alt="logo" class="img-circle">
</div>
```

Agradeço

Answer (score 3):

Se caso deseja que sempre que a classe `.relative` fique posicionada no centro, poderia utilizar o código abaixo::

**CSS**

```
.relative {
 margin:0 auto;
 float:none;
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta resolve sua dúvida sobre posicionamento da sua imagem?

Answer (score 2):

Tem as classes auxiliares do bootstrap que fazem isto, neste caso a `center-block`.

[Bootstrap css imagens](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive)

> Para centralizar imagens que usam a classe .img-responsive, use .center-block, em vez de .text-center. Consulte a seção classes auxiliares para mais detalhes sobre o uso .center-block.

O `center-block` não seria nada mais que:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Muito interessante, eu desconhecia esse class. Sempre usei o text-center, mesmo sabendo que não era ideal. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

se você deseja que um objeto fique sempre no centro da tela, independente dos demais elementos, então você deve usar `position: fixed`, ancorar ela nas extremidades da tela, usar um tamanho fixo e `margem: auto`:

```css
.centro {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/42608.png');
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centro"></div>
```

se forma alterativa ao `margin: auto`, você pode usar um `transform: traslate(-50%, -50%)`para deslocar o elemento.

```css
.centro {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/42608.png');
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centro"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra opção seria:

```
.relative{ 
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, você precisa definir o tamanho dela primeiramente. Definindo o tamanho, você pode aplicar o `margin: auto;` que ela ficará centralizada.

```
.relative {
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
}
```